# Jenkins Pipeline bat / powershell encoding - show umlauts

Tags: powershell, batch-file, encoding, command-line, jenkins-pipeline

How can I display German umlauts in windows bat / powershell which is called via jenkins pipeline script?

Even though I change the code page, I get the same wrong result in all cases: `Ã¤` instead of `ä`.
I already defined global environment variables `LC_ALL = 'de_DE.UTF-8'`, `LANG = 'de_De.UTF-8'` and `LANGUAGE = 'de_DE.UTF-8'` in jenkins but it didn't change anything.

Thanks for your help and responses!

Test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "batch ----------"
                bat "chcp & echo ä"
                bat "chcp 850 & echo ä"
                bat "chcp 1252 & echo ä"

                echo "powershell ------"
                powershell "chcp; echo ä"
                powershell "chcp 850; echo ä"
                powershell "chcp 1252; echo ä"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
batch ----------
11:21:43  [Pipeline] bat
11:21:44  
11:21:44  XXX\pipeline_test1>chcp   & echo Ã¤ 
11:21:44  Active code page: 850
11:21:44  Ã¤
11:21:44  [Pipeline] bat
11:21:44  
11:21:44  XXX\pipeline_test1>chcp 850   & echo Ã¤ 
11:21:44  Active code page: 850
11:21:44  Ã¤
11:21:44  [Pipeline] bat
11:21:44  
11:21:44  XXX\pipeline_test1>chcp 1252   & echo Ã¤ 
11:21:44  Active code page: 1252
11:21:44  Ã¤
11:21:44  [Pipeline] echo
11:21:44  powershell ------
11:21:44  [Pipeline] powershell
11:21:46  Active code page: 65001
11:21:46  Ã¤
11:21:46  [Pipeline] powershell
11:21:47  Active code page: 850
11:21:47  Ã¤
11:21:47  [Pipeline] powershell
11:21:49  Active code page: 1252
11:21:49  Ã¤
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `Ã¤` is the result of interpreting the UTF-8 encoded letter `ä` as an ANSI string (current code page). As an experiment, launch Notepad++, set encoding to "ANSI", paste `Ã¤`, set encoding to "UTF-8" (not convert!). You will see letter `ä`.

Both `bat` and `powershell` steps have an `encoding` parameter.
Pass `'UTF-8'` to get the correct output:

```
bat encoding: 'UTF-8', script: "echo ä"
```

Comment: Worked, thank you very much :-) I don't know why I didn't test the most obvious thing... :D